# Reach field in invoice report

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I need to extend invoice report with field note. but I'm getting error that field does not exist. I'm stuck and don't know how to reach that field. did tried with `partner_id.note` too but also getting error.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="report_invoice_document" inherit_id="account.report_invoice_document">
            <xpath expr="//div[@class='page']/*[last()]" position="after">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <span t-esc="o.note"/><br/>
                        <div class="left_sign_block">
                            <span>Note</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

```py
class AccountInvoiceTax(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice.tax'

    note = fields.Text(related='tax_id.note', string='Note')
```

> QWebException: "'account.invoice' object has no attribute 'note'" while evaluating 'o.note'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extended the model `account.invoice.tax` and not `account.invoice`. The error message is correct. So either you extend invoice or you have to use `note` from the invoice tax lines (`tax_line_ids`).

Comment: like  <span t-esc="tax_line_ids.tax_id.note"/> ?

Comment: Depends on how many tax lines are on that invoice. In Germany in general there could be two tax lines, if things with 19% VAT and 7% VAT were invoiced. So you either need a for loop or if you are sure, that there is only one you can use `<span t-if="tax_line_ids" t-esc="tax_line_ids[0].note"/>`

Comment: still getting QWebException: "'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'" while evaluating
'tax_line_ids[0].note'

Comment: whoops sorry missed the record you're printing -> `o`. It should be `<span t-if="o.tax_line_ids" t-esc="o.tax_line_ids[0].note"/>`

Comment: <tr t-foreach="o.tax_line_ids" t-as="t">
                            <span t-field="t.note"/> another solution as you can have notes from multiply lines.

Comment: That is what i mean with a for loop ;-)